# How to insert "concat(col1+'-'+col2)" into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012

I want to insert a record into the database, but I get an error because of this '-'

```
INSERT INTO tblTransactionLogs (data, page, insertDate) 
    VALUES ('SELECT id, CONCAT(newcode, '-', shadeno) AS clothcode, CAST(ISNULL(T_Mtrs, 0) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) - CAST(ISNULL(Used, 0) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS rem, rate FROM tbl_cloth ORDER BY clothcode', '--', '2019-09-15')
```

I get this error:

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the subtract operator

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're attempting to insert an SQL Statement into the `data` column.

When attempting to use the `'` char as a part of a string in SQL Server, you need to escape it by multiplying it:

```
INSERT INTO tblTransactionLogs (data,page,insertDate) 
VALUES('select id,CONCAT(newcode,''-'',shadeno) as clothcode,cast(ISNULL(T_Mtrs,0) as decimal(10,2))-cast(ISNULL(Used,0) as decimal(10,2)) as rem,rate from tbl_cloth  order by clothcode','--','2019-09-15')
```

However, please note that storing SQL statements in a table for later execution might be a security risk, if these SQL statements are created by user input (this is called [second order SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Second_order_SQL_injection))

Comment: yes i know the risk but it is for my development requirement,but i cannot alter the statement as it is the query which is being executed ,how can i put ''-'' ,it will give me the error.

Comment: The apostrophes will be escaped, not actually doubled. When you get the data out of the table (using `select data from tblTransactionLogs...`) the query apostrophes will not be doubled.

Answer (score 0):

you should use this structure:

INSERT INTO tblTransactionLogs (data,page,insertDate) 
select x,y,z from tblY

Comment: can you please elaborate